# Aligning labels to bar chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, bar-chart

I'm trying to configure a bar chart but am having trouble with labeling the `rect` elements themselves.  Here is what I have currently and the output I'm getting:

```
svg.selectAll("svg")
            .data(chartData)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.value;
            })
            .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                return i * (width / chartData.length) + (width / chartData.length / 2);
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return Math.min(450, height - (d.value * 6) + 30);
            })
            .attr("class", "bar-chart-label");
```

Output:

[image]

Notice how the ticks don't line up.  What am I doing wrong?  I have also tried toggling the `text-anchor: middle` CSS tag, and while it changes things it doesn't really solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I added a jsbin example to show what I'm doing: http://jsbin.com/cugozihadi/edit?js,output.

Comment: What's most confusing to me is how at first they are to the left of the bars, then at the end they end up to the right of them.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the issue. You're not adding the text to the rectangles in this case, you are adding it to the svg element directly. What you should be doing is:

1. Create the SVG element. (I'm not sure why you are doing svg.selectAll("svg") because that selects svg inside svg...which you shouldn't do)
2. Append  tags to it (literally the group tag).
3. Add the rectangles and the text to those groups.
4. Add axes and other information to the chart.

Look at a very basic example here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304 Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering @ivanempire.  I might be doing things a bit differently...I made up a simple jsbin example to show you how I'm doing it: http://jsbin.com/cugozihadi/edit?js,output.  Take a look there and see if that makes any more sense.

Comment: Got it, right, the line `svg.selectAll("svg")` is what is causing the problem. I made a quick example of how you add groups and put text into them here: http://jsbin.com/farutoxasa/edit?js,output Edit 1: Crap I pressed enter by accident. Inspect the SVG to see how the text and bars are grouped.